# How can I automatically add a post with Latin characters?

Tags: wp-insert-post, encoding

I would like to add a post in Wordpress with cURL (php) and I have this string to add as a content:

```
$text = "Trovato, assieme a Massimo e Anna, in una cantina di Via Barrili a Milano, con un'infezione agli occhi che ha provocato nei tre fratelli gradi diversi di cecità. Ci vede poco ed è molto timoroso. Con alcuni volontari ha creato un buon rapporto di fiducia. Ben inserito con gli altri gatti del reparto."
```

This is the conversion I make:

```
$content =  htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE );
```

The Post is created successfully but instead of è in the post I get a ? symbol inside a rhombus

[image: WP Post Preview]

Script on WP side:

```
require_once("wp-load.php");
error_reporting( E_ALL );

error_log("--- Received POST ---\r\n", 3, "./mqtest.log");
error_log(print_r($_POST,1), 3, "./mqtest.log");
error_log("\r\n", 3, "./mqtest.log");

$my_post = array(       
    //'post_type' => "post",    
    'post_content' =>  $_POST["content"],
    'post_title' => $_POST["name"]
);

try {

    $wp_error = "";
    error_log("Creating POST in Wordpress...\r\n", 3, "./mqtest.log");
    error_log(print_r($my_post,1), 3, "./mqtest.log");
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

[cut]
```

any suggestion please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars()` only converts &, ", ', < and >. To also convert (encode, really) accented characters, you need to use `htmlentities()`, and depending on the rest of your setup you may also have to specify which encoding to use. So:

```
$content =  htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8' );
```

(Substitute `'ISO-8859-1'` for `'UTF-8'` if necessary, though it probably won't be.)

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried both with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Same here, not working.